# wcf client test in vs 2010 tools

Tags: test-management, c#, visualstudio, web-service

wcf client test
I am using wcf test client in vs 2010 tools. 
First when i started tool, values came with null.
I want to change value's dropdownlist with my default values.
How can i do it?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to [this blog post](http://dotnetmentors.com/how-to-start-with-creating-wcf-services-and-test-using-wcftestclient.aspx) (bullet 11. Testing WCF Service with WCFTestClient) you should double click the request in the left three where you can setup input and the expected response.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I want to set values first. And when I open the method from left, it came's with values. How can i do it?

Comment: What kind of values? Your screenshot shows (null) which means no value: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?WhatIsNull

Comment: when ı double click method, it don't come null value. it come my default value.